# Form submission, react-hook-form and state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I would like to have a button that displays "Edit" to enter Edit mode and (using the same button) "Save" to submit the form.

My problem is that it already *submits* the form upon pressing the button while the button text "Edit" is showing.

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sanne-hzo899?file=/src/App.js:0-1040), containing the code below.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  //Setting up state
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  //Handler for entering edit mode.
  const handleEnterEditMode = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
    console.log("Edit mode entered.");
  };

  //Handler that runs on form submission.
  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log("Form submitted.");
  };

  //Setting up some react-hook-forms variables according to their docs
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset
  } = useForm();

  //In render:

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
        <Button
          {...(isEditing ? { type: "submit" } : {})}
          {...(!isEditing ? { onClick: handleEnterEditMode } : {})}
        >
          {!isEditing ? "Edit" : "Save"}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button inside of a Form element will always fire a Submit event by default. You can give give the button a type attribute of "button", or add a preventDefault() to the onClick method to override this.

Comment: Thanks, yes, tricky to know the default behaviour on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```js
< Button
type = { isSubmiting ? "submit" : null }
>
{!isEditing ? "Edit" : "Save"
} 
</Button>
```

and also move your `onClick` condition inside `handleEnterEditMode` method

Comment: Thanks for the shortening suggestion! It turns out the other answer allowed me to solve this without introducing another state variable isSubmiting. :)